# Django-Haystack List of nodes should not include schema information (http://): 'http://127.0.0.1:9200'

Tags: django, django-haystack

Any time I update my indexes in django-haystack I get the message `"List of nodes should not include schema information (http://): 'http://127.0.0.1:9200'."`

What does this mean exactly, and why am I seeing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing it because you have that 'http://' as part of your host. You should not be including it. Elasticsearch-py actually strips it out when it is present. See:

[https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py#L37](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#L37)

If you had 
    `ftp://127.0.0.1:9200`    , the 'ftp' would be would be your scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) and the code would still strip it off and complain. I haven't dug around the guts enough, but maybe the motivation is that it's reserving the right to prepend different schema as necessary.